# Determining best temporal autocorrelation structure

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, generalized-additive-model

I am modelling change in the mass of an animal over time with a GAM.  These animals are caught at one of two ages (1 or 2, but 1's never become 2's in the subsequent year).  I also have a large number of sites in my analysis.

The most simple model I am considering is:

```
mm <- gamm(MASS ~ s(YEAR.s, SITE, bs = "fs", by = AGE, k = 5), data = df)
```

Where YEAR.s is a continuous variable that has been centered and scaled, and SITE and AGE are factors.

(Partial) autocorrelation plots show a lot autocorrelation in the timeseries.

```
acf(resid(mm$lme, type = "normalized"))
pacf(resid(mm$lme, type = "normalized"))
```

[image]
[image]

I know there are three different correlation structure classes (corARM1, corARMA, corCAR1) that I could add to my model, but I'm not certain about the best one to use for this situation.

Also, I'm assuming that I would include both SITE and AGE as grouping factors, but I'm not sure if it will be an issue that not all AGEs are found at all SITEs (e.g., SITE A might have AGE 1 & 2, but SITE B only has AGE 1 and SITE C only has AGE 2).  Between the two factors, making sure that I've included SITE is probably more important than AGE.

Finally, not all sites are monitored in each year of the timeseries (min. 20 years of data over a ~50 year timeseries).